# System design question : Using GCP FCM for in app notifications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, system-design

This is a design question

I am working on a project with Java spring boot backend and react frontend.

My requirement is, I need to send a notification from the backend (at any point in time) to a specific user. If the user is logged in, the notification should appear to him (and get stored in redux). If not, the notification should not be shown to anyone. Later on when the user logs in, the user should see the notification.

My design is, whenever a notification needs to be sent, I parallelly save it in the database, while also send it to FCM parallelly. If I get an acknowledgement from FCM that the user has read it (which is the part I'm figuring out how), I can delete the notification in the database. If I don't get the acknowledgement to the backend, the notification would remain in the database. Later on, when the user logs in, I'll pull all the notifications from the database (since the ones in the database will be the ones he hasn't read).

So my question is, does FCM send back any such acknowledgements to the backend? If yes, is there any documentation you can share with me? If not, what is the best way to send back an acknowledgement? Can any FCM/GCP feature provide this? Or is there any completely alternate solutions to the problem?

Also, do we have to create FCM tokens each time a user logs in? What would be the best place to save it in my design?

Thanks